# How do I change UV mapping without destroying the look of the model?

Tags: uv

Normally, if I want to change the type of UV mapping means that I will destroy the look of the model as the mapping no longer corresponds with the image.

Is there a way to change UV mapping and have Blender recalculate what was painted where on the model to reflect the new mapping?

Comment: One thing you could try is re-baking it. Duplicate the model and change the UVs on that model to your liking, then bake the old mesh's texture onto the new mesh's texture.